# Need to fetch count of live instances per min from database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database

- Table name `PerformanceUserData`
- Columns: StartDate as datetime, enddate as datetime,ip address, instance

For each row instance value is 1.

Sample data is

```
2/21/2014 10:39:17 AM   2/21/2014 10:40:24 AM   192.168.1.51    1
2/21/2014 10:40:24 AM   2/21/2014 10:41:57 AM   192.168.1.51    1
2/21/2014 3:51:29 PM    2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM    192.168.1.12    1
2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM    2/21/2014 3:52:06 PM    192.168.1.12    1
2/21/2014 3:52:06 PM    2/21/2014 3:52:39 PM    192.168.1.12    1
2/21/2014 3:52:39 PM    2/21/2014 3:53:12 PM    192.168.1.12    1
```

Input to query is startdate and enddate

If start date is 2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM and enddate is 2/21/2014 5:51:30 PM
I need data per min from 3.15 PM to 3.16 PM

Data need

```
Time               number of instances
3.51 to 3.52       2
3.52 to 3.53       2
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: We have make directory and push all entries into it and then take join on other table But it will take huge time

Answer (score 1):

@gordon is right.i am lil confuse about sample date,
try something like this,

```
 Declare @PerformanceUserData Table(StartDate datetime, enddate datetime,ip varchar(20), instance int)
 insert into @PerformanceUserData
select  '2/21/2014 10:39:17 AM','2/21/2014 10:40:24 AM','192.168.1.51', 1 union all
select  '2/21/2014 10:40:24 AM','2/21/2014 10:41:57 AM','192.168.1.51',1  union all
select  '2/21/2014 3:51:29 PM','2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM','192.168.1.12',1  union all
select  '2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM','2/21/2014 3:52:06 PM','192.168.1.12',1  union all
select  '2/21/2014 3:52:06 PM','2/21/2014 3:52:39 PM','192.168.1.12',1  union all
select  '2/21/2014 3:52:39 PM','2/21/2014 3:53:12 PM','192.168.1.12',1
--select * from @PerformanceUserData
Declare @startdate datetime='2/21/2014 3:51:30 PM'
Declare @enddate datetime='2/21/2014 5:51:30 PM'
Declare @t Table(dates datetime, rn int)
;with cte  as
(
select @startdate dates,
1 rn
union all
select DATEADD(minute,1,dates),rn+1 from cte  where dates<@enddate 
)

insert into @t
select * from cte option(maxrecursion 0)

select a.dates,b.dates
,(select count(*) from @PerformanceUserData where StartDate 
between a.dates and b.dates)[number of instances]
 from @t a inner join @t b on b.rn-a.rn=1
```